# display the full column size in zeppelin %sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, livy

I simply want to display the column without truncate into a select where i have an array or a Map with a very big lenth.

I use zeppelin to query a df register as temp table:

```
%livy.sql
select * from maTable
```

I would like to have the full length of the Consommeur column
I get something like:
[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi, what version of Zeppelin and livy you are using? And it would be nice to attach the original value of the `Consommeur` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is solved in version 0.8.0.
The problem is that by default Zeppelin truncates the string values.

In version 0.8.0 `zeppelin.livy.spark.sql.field.truncate` can be set to `false` (by default is set to true). This can be done going to the interpreter settings and adding that property.

Extra information on the solution to the issue here: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2201

Original Jira ticket for the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1965